# My Wamp is bugging down?

Tags: wamp, wampserver

I installed mysql and wamp 2.4 in my server .  I made my wamp automatically start upon startup and also disabled wampmysqld so that it will not conflict with mysql.

Then i put my wamp online .

Last month I can smoothly access my server in my LAN network.

But sometimes this week, I cannot access my server's localhost page on my LAN network. I have to open wamp again and and restart all services and its annoying . There are days that wamp will work the whole day and sometimes you need to restart all services again what seems to be the problem and how to solve this?

I open apache logfile and find this error

```
[Fri Mar 11 13:45:36.654882 2016] [core:notice] [pid 3200:tid 492] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\wamp\\bin\\apache\\apache2.4.4\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/wamp/bin/apache/Apache2.4.4' 
[Fri Mar 11 13:45:36.655882 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3200:tid 492] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 3568 
[Fri Mar 11 13:45:37.149910 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3568:tid 300] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
```

Comment: You could look in the server error logs to see whether anything is out of the ordinary

Comment: Check if port 80 is on use (Skype for instance will use this one when starting)

Comment: I open apache logfile and find this error



[Fri Mar 11 13:45:36.654882 2016] [core:notice] [pid 3200:tid 492] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\wamp\\bin\\apache\\apache2.4.4\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/wamp/bin/apache/Apache2.4.4'
[Fri Mar 11 13:45:36.655882 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3200:tid 492] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 3568
[Fri Mar 11 13:45:37.149910 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3568:tid 300] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.

Comment: They are not error messages, they are just normal reporting of an Apache startup